# JavaFx Canvas : how to do XOR drawing?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm looking for a method like [GraphicsContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html)`.setMode( GraphicsContextMode.XOR )` but I haven't found it.

Below a [SSCCE](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://sscce.org/&ei=hpzSUv22EaGe0QXSjoGwAw&usg=AFQjCNFdqWH-Hxu7Vlsk6vBvl9vWtnAdrw&sig2=uWWGvW_UnM3pmZtBiH-fXg) to draw some shapes (actually limited to lines), with two methods: complete redraw at each mouse drag event or XOR drawing (not working):

```
public class XorApp extends Application {

   private static final boolean HAVE_XOR = false;

   private final Canvas       canvas   = new Canvas( 800, 600 );
   private final List< Line > segments = new LinkedList<>();
   private /* */ Line         segment  = null;

   private static void draw( GraphicsContext g, Line line ) {
      g.strokeLine(
         line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), line.getEndX(), line.getEndY());
   }

   private void redrawAll( GraphicsContext g ) {
      g.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
      for( final Line line : segments ) {
         draw( g, line );
      }
   }

   protected void started( double x, double y ) {
      if( segment != null ) {
         ended( segment.getEndX(), segment.getEndY());
      }
      segment = new Line( x, y, -1.0, -1.0 );
   }

   protected void dragged( double x, double y ) {
      if( segment == null ) {
         return;
      }
      final GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
      if( segment.getEndX() > -1.0 ) {
         if( HAVE_XOR ) {
            // Redraw the last segment erase it, thanks to XOR mode
            draw( g, segment );
         }
         else {
            redrawAll( g );
         }
      }
      segment.setEndX( x );
      segment.setEndY( y );
      draw( g, segment );
   }

   protected void ended( double x, double y ) {
      dragged( x, y );
      segments.add( segment );
      redrawAll( canvas.getGraphicsContext2D());
      segment = null;
   }

   @Override
   public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
      if( HAVE_XOR ) {
         //-- SET XOR MODE HERE --
      }
      final BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
      bp.setCenter( canvas );
      stage.setScene( new Scene( bp ));
      stage.centerOnScreen();
      stage.show();
      canvas.setOnMousePressed( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
         @Override public void handle( MouseEvent event ) {
            started( event.getX(), event.getY()); }});
      canvas.setOnMouseDragged( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
         @Override public void handle( MouseEvent event ) {
            dragged( event.getX(), event.getY()); }});
      canvas.setOnMouseClicked( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
         @Override public void handle( MouseEvent event ) {
            ended( event.getX(), event.getY()); }});
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      launch( args );
   }
}
```

Comment: Experiment with g.setBlendMode(...)

Comment: Experimentation done: none of the enumeration values produce XOR result

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem developing an interactive drawing program that wanted XORmode to provide drawing feedback during Mouse move events (which is how I've done it in other libraries, including Swing). I found two solutions. The first (not recommended) was a kludge of embedding a Swing JPanel, and forcing it to update when desired by calling SwingNode.setContent(), because invalidate() doesn't work in this case. That also requires an override of paintComponent.

A much better solution was to use two JavaFX Canvas objects in a StackPane. One (on the bottom) for drawing temp shapes during Mouse moves. I simply clear it (drawing a big rectangle in a background color) before drawing the temporary shape. When the shape is done (MouseReleased event), I again clear the temp canvas and draw the permanent object into the top Canvas. The top Canvas is left with its default transparent background, so that the temp shapes can be seen.